# Obfuscating AAR and its dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, obfuscation, aar

I am using gradle and Android Studio to create a library, let's call it library *A*. The library-module A in my project depends on a different library-module, *B*. The reason that A and B are seperate is that there are also apps in this project that depend on library A *or* B, but not both. Simply put, I do not want to keep these library modules separate in my codebase.

I want to deliver two AARs:

- A.aar
- B.aar

I want to obfuscate the classes in A.aar and B.aar. Currently if I switch on obfuscation on release builds of A, it works. But as soon as I switch on obfuscation on B, the build process of A fails, because the referenced symbols in B cannot be found.

Apparently the obfuscation of these two libraries isn't synchronized. This is want I want.

Or I would like to produce a single obfuscated AAR, which contains all dependencies, but as I understand it, this isn't possible with gradle/Andorid Studio.

EDIT:
I am using proguard for obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question it seems like library A has dependancy on library B. If the dependency is on public API the you just need to ensure that public APIs of B.aar has not been obfuscated.

If you have dependency on internal code, you can:

- Make the class as part of your public API **OR**
- If its a single class then duplicate it in library A **OR**
- If there are bunch of classes then you can create a new module and make Library A & B depend on the new module

If you want to ship library A.aar with B.aar as dependancy, you can publish it as local or central maven repository. More details can be found [here](https://github.com/wupdigital/android-maven-publish)

If you decide to make it local repository then you need to zip the repository and deliver it to your user. All the dependencies will be handled appropriately

You can obfuscate the classes in B.aar as follows:

1. Build and publish library B
2. Publish library A in same repository and navigate the resulting repository to locate B.aar. Make copy of B.aar and Unzip copy of aar, either by changing .aar extention to .zip and using zip/unzip software or directly use 7-Zip software
3. Copy the classes.jar from the package and paste it under libs/ directory of library A. Remember to rename the jar file
4. Include following line in you build.gradle

   dependencies {

   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     ...

   }
5. Remove classes.jar from original aar without unzipping it. 7-Zip software is capable of doing it
6. Obfuscate library A. B.aar's classes will be obfuscated as well.